# Problem with missing files on syncing with git-p4

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

I'm getting a recurring issue with git-p4.  On syncing with `git-p4 clone //depot/project/main` the majority of files are synced up but there are a number of exceptions for which I can find no apparent common denominators.  I created a separate Perforce workspace to use with git-p4 and globally set the properties `git-p4.client` to this workspace and `git-p4.useclientspec` to true.

On the Perforce server, we version projects as follows:

> //depot/project/main
>   //depot/project/1.0.0
>   //depot/project/1.1.0

Calling `p4 info` gives the following version information for the Perforce installation.  Summary: It's old.

> Server version: P4D/NTX86/2006.2/113956 (2007/01/04)

Can anyone provide leads to debugging this issue or recommend documentation as to what versions of Perforce are supported?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a direct perforce workspace then `p4 info` will tell you what the version of the server is.

Comment: Thanks!  Adding this info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

See my commit in this [GitHub repo](http://github.com/scottj97/git/commits/fix_for_old_perforce) for a fix I had to make to git-p4 to work with an old version of p4.

Unfortunately I don't remember the details of my change. At a glance it appears to only affect `git-p4 submit`.

Comment: I've tried this out, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to resolve the problem.  Thanks for the lead though -- if I come across a fix I'll forward a patch to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem- some files being not loaded for no apparent reason- although I believe that mine is caused by a partial sync interrupted by an overriding path of files to load, then a forced sync. My problem was solved by refreshing my local repository from the ground up... it takes a large chunk of time but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because our Perforce server was running on Linux and file names were case sensitive. Any consequent CLs become case sensitive too.
The git-p4 collects and applies change lists in the historical order from Perforce on the local filesystem.

When I started the git-p4.py on my Windows box from a case sensitive P4 repository and I had a change which removed a duplicate file (with diference in capitals only) it actually removed the original file because Windows doesn't distinguish it and Python doesn't know about this issue.

The simple solution was to start conversion from Linux box, which made it working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues some times, and I noticed that if file or directory was renamed at some point like project/main and latter was renamed to Project/main, clone will no include later one as you are only sync the path with lower case